# How can I find a word in a string of characters where the characters may be separated by whitespaces

Tags: c++, computer-science

Basically what the program needs to do is input a word and a string of characters and find that word in the string where that word can be separated by whitespaces.

For example:

> Input string: `"this is a c a m e l"`
>
> Word to find: `camel`

In this case, the word should be successfully found.

Here's what I have so far.

```
{
    string sec_message;
    string line;


    cout << "Enter your secret message: ";
    cin >> sec_message;

    getline(cin, line);
    cin.ignore();

    for(int i =0; i<sec_message.length(); i++){
        if(isspace(line.at(i))){
            line[i] = line[i+1];
            
        }
        else{
            if(sec_message[i] == line)
        }
        

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you find the word breaks (not code just explain please)  eg is this _"w h i t e s p a c e"_ one word or two ?

Comment: Do you just want a true/false answer to whether the word "camel" is in the string? Or do you need to know where in the string it is? Or something else?

Comment: i just need to find that word it will be separated by whitespaces in the input by the user.

Comment: @Bubbelz so how do you find the words here is  _"w h i t e s p a c e"_ meant to be  `whitespace` or `white space` what are your rules for word breaks if the words can contain spaces ?

Comment: @RichardCritten I just need to find one word which is camel if that word is found then you cout a arbitrary value. Im just confused about finding it when there are spaces in between the characters so basically im struggling on how noting that camel is the same as c a m e l

Comment: What determines whether `came` or `camel` or both are the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the spaces from the line before comparing

Example of removing spaces

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string str = "h e ll o  the re";

    auto it = std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), isspace);
    str.erase(it, str.end());

    std::cout << str << "\n";

    if (str.find("hello") != std::string::npos) {
        std::cout << "It contains hello\n";
    }
}
```

Generates output

```cpp
hello
it contains hello
```

Comment: If you look at OPs example _"this is a c a m e l"_ this approach would remove the gaps between words producing _"thisisacamel"_ which could produce new words see my comment

Comment: I think the question is badly formed and needs clarity before we can answer it

Comment: So the point of the program is to find that word in the sentence. I just need to know how to find it i don't know how because of the whitespace. Like i need to break it down character by character

Comment: @Bubbelz Check my other answer. Its like you have just copy-pasted a school assignment though. You should consider formulating your own questions, then you might have already solved it yourself

Comment: @Lasersköld I was able to figure it out thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So separate by tabs and spaces and generate pairs.

Like this then

```cpp
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    auto ss = std::istringstream{"xxx\tyyy\thello there"}; // You can use cin instead of istringstream

    std::string x, y;

    ss >> x >> y; // Read the first two words

    std::cout << "first part separated by tabs " << x << ", " << y << "\n";

    // Read the rest words, two by two
    for (std::string word1, word2; ss >> word1 >> word2; ) 
    {
        std::cout << "Pair: " << word1 << ", " << word2;
    }
}
```

```cpp
first part separated by tabs xxx, yyy
Pair: hello, there
```